# UI5 pass model property into addStyleClass

Tags: sapui5

I'd like to bind a list to a model with the following code and having trouble passing a parameter into the addStyleClass function to dyanmically apply a CSS class.

Here's my coding:

```
var oList = new sap.m.List("list", {
    //headerText : "L+P",
    growing : true,
});
...

oList.bindItems({path: "/LP_ListSet",
            //filters : oFilter,
            //sorter: oSorter,
            template: new sap.m.CustomListItem({
                type: sap.m.ListType.Navigation,
            ...
                content: [
                    new sap.m.Text("descrip",{ text: "{Description}"}),
                    new sap.m.Text("mengelabel", {text: "Menge: "}),
                    new sap.m.Text("menge",{ text: "{Quantity}" }),
                    new sap.m.Text("einheitenlabel", {text: "Einheiten: "}),
                    new sap.m.Text("einheiten",{ text: "{UnitDescr}" }),
                    new sap.m.Text("preislabel", {text: "Preis: "}),
                    new sap.m.Text("preis",{ text: { path : 'Price',
                        formatter : function(value) {
                            return oController.currencyFormat(value);
                        }} }),

                    new sap.m.Text("gultigablabel", {text: "Gültig Ab: "}),
                    new sap.m.Text("gultigAb",{ 
                                text : { path : 'Priceva',
                                formatter : function(value) {
                                    return oController.dateFormat(value);
                                }} }), 

                    ]
                }
            ).addStyleClass(oController.getClassForQuantity((╯°□°）╯︵┻━┻)) //Here I'd like to pass the Quantity parameter
```

If I pass the parameter like this `.addStyleClass(oController.getClassForQuantity('{Quantity}')` my resulting CSS class is quantity{Quantity} instead of quantity0 or quantity1.

The function `getClassForQuantity` is defined as

```
getClassForQuantity: function(quantity) {
    console.log("quantity is: "+ quantity);
    return "quantity" + quantity; //should output quantity0, quantity1 etc. but outputs quantity{Quantity}
}
```

The example CSS is:

```
.quantity0 {
    border-left: 3px solid green;
}
.quantity1 {
    border-left: 3px solid blue;
}
.quantity2 {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}
```

How can I pass that Quantity parameter for each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use factory function instead template

```
function customListFactory(sId, oContext) {
  var quantity = oContext.getProperty("Quantity");

  return /*you template*/.addStyleClass("quantity" + quantity);
}

oList.bindItems({
  path: "/LP_ListSet",
  factory: customListFactory
}
```

Comment: Now it only shows one single entry in the list. I have encapsulated the Template into its own variable. And: it applies multiple classes to that one single item (quantity1 and quantity2). Any idea why?

Comment: Check the console for possible error messages. Example http://jsbin.com/femisi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: yes, got an error: 'Uncaught Error: Error: adding element with duplicate id 'descrip''. I had to remove all Id's in my content array's object's. Then it worked. I am just wondering why it worked before introducing the factory - though there must have been several Id's multiple times. Big thanks!

Comment: My guess is that when using a template SAPUI5 clones the template and automatically appends the id with "-clone#". At least that is how it worked for me in xml views. When you use a factory you are trying to create the control from scratch each time the factory is called trying to instance it with the same id.